# Eclipse + Ubuntu Arrow Keys and Backspace Not Working

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and Eclipse Juno. This happens frequently: The arrow keys and backspace stop working in the editor. The only way to resolve it is to restart the computer. Restarting Eclipse does not help. Anyone had this issue or knows the solution? Thanks.

UPDATE: I have a Dell laptop with a touch screen. I noticed that this problem starts happening after I touch the screen. Is there a way to disable touch on Ubuntu?

UPDATE 2: If I disable N-Trig on Ubuntu, that would solve the problem. Is there a way to turn it off permanently, without start-up scripts, etc.?

UPDATE 3: It seems like if I use the touch pad after touching the screen, the problem would go away. So, if I just touch the screen, the arrow keys in Eclipse stop working. Then, if I use the touch pad or even just touch it, the arrow keys in Eclipse start working again. VERY strange, but at least it solved my issue for now.

Comment: I just can't see this being a function of the touch screen. Does this happen in *all* applications after touching the screen, or just Eclipse?

Comment: Only Eclipse. I tried it a few times, and the touchscreen is definitely the culprit. Don't ask me why!

Comment: happening to me with Dell XPS 12 and ubuntu 12.04

Comment: 'UPDATE 3' helped me with my Thinkpad "t410s". Once I do enable the touchpad (Fn+F8) and use it, eclipse works fine again. WTF?!?!

Answer (score 2):

According to this link: http://developerbits.blogspot.com/2012/03/arrow-keys-and-backspace-stop-working.html

You just need to press all of the mouse keys and it will come back. You probably have a mouse button in a down state which causes problems for eclipse. I've verified on my end that keeping a button down prevents arrow keys from working in eclipse.

Comment: In my case, touching all mouse buttons completely froze the keyboard (instead of unlocking). Closing and reopening the editor solves the problem. (Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 12.04, no touchscreen)

Answer (score 1):

To disable the touch screen, this page should help: https://superuser.com/questions/371617/permanently-disable-dell-latitude-2120-touchscreen-in-x-org-upon-start-up-and-su

Essentially, you need to run a certain command on startup. I can clarify that if you need help there, but the command disables the xinput device for the touch screen.

Comment: Thanks. I get: unable to find device IDEACOM  IDC 6651.

Comment: that's the particular device that guy had. He said he got the device details by running "xinput list" (without the quotes). Do you see your touchscreen listed there?

Comment: I assume it's N-Trig MultiTouch. I turned it off and the touch is gone. There has to be a way to turn N-Trig off permanently, right?

Comment: There may be a way, I'm just not familiar with it. The way the guy in the link did it was by adding a startup script to run the command. Put the command to disable the touchscreen into "disable.sh" in your home folder. Right click, properties on that file. Go to Permissions and Allow executing file as program. Then search on "Startup Applications" in the dash, and add it there, so the command is "bash /home/YOURUSERNAME/disable.sh"

Comment: on my Dell XPS 12 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS this trick will disable my touch screen, but doesn't solve the problem of the broken backspace and arrow keys in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply caused by the loosing of focus on your editor. The focus is still on any last popup window.

You can do something like: show up any more popup window (by right click on editor and select Quick Outline for instance) and then press Esc, the focus will back immediately and you can use your arrow keys as usual.

**Right Click (on editor) -> Quick Outline -> press Esc key.**