# Shortcuts in Eclipse work intermittently or don't work at all

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, using Eclipse Luna, very often I experience that shortcuts stop working (for example: Ctrl + C, Ctrl + Z, Ctrl + R).

Sometimes I'm able to "get around" by clicking outside the code editor (for example, by clicking on a folder in the Project Explorer window) and click back in the code editor. Of course this is really annoying and inefficient but I haven't been able to find another way to do it.

I have checked that Ubuntu is not replacing the shortcuts for other actions.

Do you have any ideas what could it be?

Comment: I've seen a few similar reports. Some people suggested pressing all mouse buttons at once. Also [one person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447049/eclipse-ubuntu-arrow-keys-a0nd-backspace-not-working) found the disabling the touch pad on their laptop helped. I get this in Luna (but not in Kelper) and nothing but a restart helps. I get it when editing json files (as text files) and then doing a find and replace. After that shortcuts, cursor and backspace stop working.